# Need parent object from the provided array

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have the below object and if I send some array I need the parents of those object.

Lets say if I send {Id:113} , It should return [11,1]

```
[  
   {  
      Id:1,
      Name:"Test",
      children:[  
         {  
            Id:11,
            Name:"Test",
            children:[  
               {  
                  Id:113,
                  Name:"Test",
                  children:[  

                  ]
               },
               {  
                  Id:114,
                  Name:"Test",
                  children:[  

                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            Id:12,
            Name:"Test",
            children:[  

            ]
         },
         {  
            Id:13,
            Name:"Test",
            children:[  
               {  
                  Id:115,
                  Name:"Test",
                  children:[  
                     {  
                        Id:1111,
                        Name:"Test",
                        children:[  

                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            Id:14,
            Name:"Test",
            children:[  

            ]
         }
      ]
   }   {  
      Id:2,
      Name:"Test",
      children:[  

      ]
   }
]
```

I am able to fetch each children item by using the below code.

```
this.selectedOMStructure = function (structure, id) {
            _.each(structure, function (_item) {
                if (_item.Id == id) {
                    _item.isChecked = !_item.isChecked;
                    if (_item.children) {
                        _this.checkAllChildren(_item.children, _item.isChecked);
                    } else {
                        return;
                    }
                } else if (_item.children) {
                    _this.selectedOMStructure(_item.children, id);
                }
            })
        }

        this.checkAllChildren = function (structure, value) {
            _.each(structure, function (_item) {
                _item.isChecked = value;
                if (_item.children) {
                    _this.checkAllChildren(_item.children, value);
                } else {
                    return;
                }
            })
        }
```

But I have no idea how to find the parents of mentioned ID

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, please show your code/effort and what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is a better approach. Try this,
`data` will be having your array. `main()` is the entry point. And the value will be stored in `a`.

```
var a = [];

function main() {
    a = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        checkChildren(data[i], 1111);
    }
    console.log(a);
}

function checkChildren(node, id) {
    if (node.Id == id) {
        return id;
    }
    else if (node.children) {
        for (let i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
            let r = checkChildren(node.children[i], id);
            if (r != 0) {
                a.push(node.Id);
                return node.Id;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}

main();
```

Answer (score -1):

You will need to map the values from this data structure into a new data structure.

Consider using a recursive algorithm that attaches a new parent field to every item while also adding it to a map from `id` to the item.